# Ayuda con el siguiente problema

Tags: map, apache-spark, hadoop

Buenas,
Estoy tratando de resolver el siguiente problemas: "Contar cantidad de vocales y consonantes" utilizando la plataforma hadoop, técnica MapReduce.

La cuestión que me sucede es la siguiente: Al realizar la ejecución del algoritmo obtengo esta salida:

```
Consonantes 1
Consonantes 1
Consonantes 1
Consonantes 1
Consonantes 1
Consonantes 1
Consonantes 1
Consonantes 1
Consonantes 1
Consonantes 1
Consonantes 1
Consonantes 1
Vocales 1
Vocales 1
Vocales 1
Vocales 1
Vocales 1
Vocales 1
Vocales 1
Vocales 1
Vocales 1
Vocales 1
```

El texto que analizo es el siguiente: "hola hola como andas andas". Lo cierto es que si realizo el conteo de la salida manualmente la cantidad de vocales y consonantes esta bien, osea 12 consonantes y 10 vocales. Pero no se corresponde con la salida del Reduce.

Dejo la solución que he propuesto para el problema. Puede que no sea muy eficiente. Cualquier comentario sera valorado. Gracias

```
public class Vocales {

public static class MapperV extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Mapper.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itPalabras = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        caracter c = new caracter();
        while(itPalabras.hasMoreTokens()){
            String cadena = itPalabras.nextToken();
            char [] caracter = cadena.toCharArray();
            for(int i=0; i<cadena.length(); i++){
                if(c.esVocal(caracter[i])){
                    context.write(new Text ("Vocales"), new IntWritable(1));
                }else{
                    if(c.esConsonante(caracter[i])){
                        context.write(new Text("Consonantes"),new IntWritable(1));
                    }      
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}

public static class ReducerV extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>{

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Reducer.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int countVocales = 0, countConsonantes = 0;

        for(IntWritable val : values){
            if(key.toString().equals("Vocales")) countVocales += val.get();
            else countConsonantes += val.get();   
        }
        Text v = new Text("total de "+key.toString()+": ");
        Text c = new Text("total de "+key.toString()+": ");
        context.write(v , new IntWritable(countVocales));
        context.write(c , new IntWritable(countConsonantes));
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException{
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Job-Eje2");
    job.setJarByClass(Vocales.class);

    job.setMapperClass(MapperV.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setReducerClass(ReducerV.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0])); 
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}

public static class caracter{

    //Metodo que permite deteminar si un caracter es o no vocal. 
    //Con el metodo toLowerCase de la clase Character permite evitar problemas cuando se trata de vocales de mayusculas o minusculas.
    public boolean esVocal(char c){
        if(Character.toLowerCase(c) == 'a' || Character.toLowerCase(c) == 'e' || Character.toLowerCase(c) == 'i'|| Character.toLowerCase(c) == 'o' || Character.toLowerCase(c) == 'u' ){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean esConsonante(char c) {
        if(Character.isLetter(c) && (!esVocal(c))){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Ya encontre el error, se debia a que estaba pasando mal el 3er parametro de los metodos map y reduce! Gracias por la ayuda igual

Answer (score 0):

podes provar en la parte :

```
 for(int i=0; i<cadena.length(); i++){
     if(c.esVocal(caracter[i])){
        context.write(new Text ("Vocales"), new IntWritable(1));
     }else{
        if(c.esConsonante(caracter[i])){
        context.write(new Text("Consonantes"),new IntWritable(1));
     }      
  }
```

a aumentar el contador al interno del for y en fin imprimir a la salida

```
 for(int i=0; i<cadena.length(); i++){
     if(c.esVocal(caracter[i])){
        countVocales++;  // o countVocales =+ 1;
     }else if(c.esConsonante(caracter[i])){
        countConsonantes++; // o countConsonantes =+ 1;
     }      
  }
```

porque en esta parte de codigo vos estabas imprimiendo el texto "vocales: 1" y respectivamente "consonantes: 1" a cada correspondencia

espero que te pueda servir

Comment: No entendi? Osea me estas diciendo que defina "countVocales y countConsonantes" en el Map? y despues de eso ir incrementando ambos contadores (en el if), para luego, al finalizar el bucle realice lo siguiente 'context.write(new Text("Consonantes"),new IntWritable(countVocales));'

Comment: Ósea se no entendí mal en el ciclo for que te pase, estabas contando las vocales y las consonantes, solo que en vez de contar y aumentar el contador dabas como output "vocales: 1" y respectivamente "consonantes: 1"